# Failing to convert from epochmili to string

Tags: java, epoch, localdatetime, datetimeformatter, zoneid

This the epoch mili - 1526581800000

The code which am using for conversion is -

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1526581800000),ZoneId.systemDefault());      
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
```

Output which we getting-
17-May-2018 18:30:00

But Expected Output -
18-May-2018 00:00:00

Comment: That means your `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is returning the UTC zone. Why do you expect something else then?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as already mentioned in a comment, your call to `ZoneId.systemDefault()` does not return the expected `ZoneId`. That means you either have to adjust the configuration of your system/JVM or specify a `ZoneId` manually, like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                                      Instant.ofEpochMilli(1526581800000L),
                                      ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata") // SPECIFY ZONE
                                  );
    System.out.println(
            localDateTime.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                Locale.ENGLISH)
            )
    );
}
```

Output (totally independent from the system's time zone):

```
18-May-2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)`. Otherwise, a good answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks for pointing out! The locale is necessary in this case! I should have seen it in the output ^^